# autolayout not working in xcode for iphone6 simulator

Tags: xcode, ios8, autolayout

My app's layout is fine for the iphone 5 simulator but is not working for the iphone 6 simulator.  The layout does not stretch to the right and the bottom of the screen in the iphone 6 simulator.  I have tried clicking on all the autolayout check boxes in my storyboard.  I did notice that the interface builder document is set for ios 7 and above.  Is there an option for ios 8?  Can I program the layout?  Any help would be awesome!  I was going to post photos but I cant since this is my first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need my friend, is an Xcode feature called Constraints. Constraints, along with auto-layout, help you use one storyboard, and with that storyboard alone, develop for both the iPhone and iPad. Maybe you should check these tutorials out!-

[Brian J Coleman's Tutorial](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/autolayout-xcode6/)

I'll post the other links as comments, StackOverflow isn't letting me post them...

I used this one, i found it to be the best-

[AppCoda's Tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/)

Happy Coding!

Comment: http://mobileoop.com/how-to-use-auto-layout-in-xcode-6-for-ios-7-and-8-development